# ShowModal for an associated form

Tags: forms, delphi

I have a component with bellow properties:

```
property Form: TForm read FForm write SetForm
property BtnOK: TButton read FBtnOK write SetBtnOK
```

and a procedure behind like this:

```
procedure Execute_FormShowModal;
```

I would like to open the associated form (eg. `FormUser`) when the `Execute_FormShowModal` is executed.

I would like to mention that, the associated form is already defined and exist, but is not created.

Is there any possibility to do this?

```
procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;
var
  frm: TForm;
begin
  frm:= TForm(FForm.ClassName).Create(FParentForm); //Access Violation...
  //... here I would like to play also this the elements from this form
  //like: BtnOK.Enabled:= False;
  frm.ShowModal;
  frm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Is `FForm` a valid reference when you're calling that method?

Comment: yes, of course. I've set the value of `Form` to an existing valid form like `FormUser`

Comment: Ah, now I see one problem. You're trying to typecast the `ClassName` to a class. It should be `ClassType` instead.

Comment: Let's take this easy example: `procedure MainForm.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject); var frm: TForm; begin  frm:= TForm(FormUser.ClassType).Create(Self); frm.ShowModal; frm.Free; end;` Access Violation... :(

Comment: You don't need 'frm' if you want to instantiate FForm. FForm := TForm.Create(Self)

Comment: If i will do only like this `FForm := TForm.Create(Self)` I will just get an empty form opened. I need to open the associated pre-defined form.

Comment: So use the class type of your associated form. FForm := TMyAssociatedForm.Create(Self);

Comment: @Tom Imagine I created during design-time 2 forms :`FormMain` and `FormUser` with other elements on them (TEdit, TButtons...). Both forms have the visual design already done. `FormMain` is auto-created, but `FormUser` will be created during run-time.

Comment: @Tom During design-time, in the object inspector of the component, I just simply select the form that I want to associate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added in the comments that you are setting FForm to be equal to a valid existing form.  If so, you may not need to create anything:

```
procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;
var
  frm: TFormUser;

begin
   frm:= TFormUser(FForm);

   frm.BtnOK.Enabled:=False;

   frm.ShowModal;
   //frm.Free;
end;
```

This assumes that this valid instance you are referring to is declared

```
type
   TFormUser = class(TForm)
      BtnOK : TButton;

      // etc...
   end;
```

If you trying to make a copy of the form you might use this:

```
procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;

var
   frm: TFormUser;

begin
   frm:= TFormUser(TFormClass(FForm.ClassType).Create(FParentForm)); 

   // which is no different than:

   frm:= TFormUser.Create(FParentForm)); 

   frm.BtnOK.Enabled:=False;
   frm.ShowModal;
   frm.Free;
end;
```

If you want to manipulate the controls on the form (i.e. BtnOK), then you need to know the class type of the Form (TFormUser in this case).  So it is contradictory to be required to know the exact class type of the form and yet want to instanciate a form from a design-time established type.

---

Since you may be trying to instanciate the form without "knowing" its absolute type, your FForm property should be the **class** for the form.

Assuming you weren't publishing the "Form" property in your component, I would make these changes to your component:

```
TMyComp = class(TComponent)
   FFormClass : TFormClass;

   procedure SetFormClass(Value : TFormClass);
   property  FormClass: TFormClass read FFormClass write SetFormClass;

   procedure Execute_FormShowModal;
end;
```

The initialization code you referred to might look like this:

```
begin
  // .....

  //MyComp.Form := FormUser1;

  MyComp.FormClass := TFormUser;

  // .....

end;
```

And then "Execute_FormShowModal" becomes:

```
procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;

var
   frm: TForm;

begin
   // Check that FFormClass is not nil and perform some alternate
   //  action.
   // if FFormClass = nil then ......
   //
   frm:= FFormClass.Create(FParentForm); 
   frm.ShowModal;
   frm.Free;
end;
```

Of course, you may also want to add some code to check if FFormClass is nil and preform some alternate behavior if so, like raise an exception or showing some message or even instanciating a default form.

---

If you were publishing the Form property then it won't be able to handle the case where your FForm field value is nil because you don't know or have a specific class type to instanciate the Form.  That is:

```
frm:= TFormClass(FForm.ClassType).Create(FParentForm);
```

will simply display a blank, empty form.

---

If you want to publish this property, you could try making it a string type that carries the *name* of the form class you want to instanciate and then use RTTI to find the class:

```
uses RTTI;

TMyComp = class(TComponent)
   FFormClassName : string;

   procedure SetFormClassName(const Value : string);
   property FormClassName: string read FFormClassName write SetFormClassName;

   procedure Execute_FormShowModal;
end;


procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;

var
   frmCls : TFormClass;
   frm: TForm;

   RTTI : TRTTIContext;
   RTTIType : TRTTIType;

begin
   frmCls := nil;
   for RTTIType in RTTI.GetTypes do
      begin
         if (RTTIType.Name = FFormClassName) and (RTTIType.TypeKind = tkClass) then
            begin
               if RTTIType.Handle.TypeData.ClassType.InheritsFrom(TForm) then
                  begin
                     frmClass := TFormClass(RTTIType.Handle.TypeData.ClassType);
                     break;
                  end;
            end;
      end;

   // Check that frmCls is not nil and perform some alternate
   //  action.
   // if frmCls = nil then ......
   //
   frm:= frmCls.Create(FParentForm); 
   frm.ShowModal;
   frm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: First part of your answer with `property  FormClass` is partially working. Unfortunately before form get opened and after it get closed I receive this error: `Invalid pointer operation`. About RTTI, I tested quickly and it doesn't work `Access Violation`. I will insist.

Comment: Sorry - just realized there was a nasty formatting error in the RTTI code example.  Please retry the code, it should work.   I'm using Delphi 10.2 but this should work in any version of Delphi back to when the new RTTI was introduced.

Comment: "Invalid pointer operation" could you somehow show the exact code that generated the message.  Something is probably being free'd twice somehow.

Comment: "I will insist"  - I'm sorry, I don't know what this means.

Comment: I'm not on the computer now, but it was at free memory of object. I will come back with a clear answer. I will insist, means that i will try more to understand and test your RTTI solution. At the first test didn't work.

Comment: `_FreeMem(Pointer(Self));` under `procedure TObject.FreeInstance;` from `System` unit. Any ideea why?

Comment: You've just shown us code from the RTL.  What other items are above those in the call stack?  We would need to see your actual code.  All we could do is take wild guesses.   You've might have called "Free" on an object that is owned elsewhere and already been free'd by that other owner-object.   Or maybe it is one of an infinite other possibilities.   We really need to see that actual code.

Comment: Sorry, the error was from an object created under `FormUser`. Nothing linked to your code. I will approve this answer. The mid code with `property  FormClass: TFormClass read FFormClass write SetFormClass;` and `MyComp.FormClass := TFormUser`, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to do this?
>   Yes

Try something like this

```
uses uFForm; // Add the unit name that defined the associated form to your (TMyComp) unit uses clause

procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;
begin
   with TFForm.Create(Self) do  //TFForm is the child form
   begin
    //... here I would like to play also this the elements from this form
    BtnOK.Enabled:= False;
    Show;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are trying to typecast the **`ClassName`** to a class type that you're trying to instantiate. Instead you want to work with the metaclass that can be obtained by the **`ClassType`** method from an object instance. The next issue is that with such metaclass you need to typecast to a metaclass, not to a class, so instead of typecasting to **`TForm`** class cast to its metaclass **`TFormClass`**.

To the next part of your question, if you can *generally* access a specific class members of an object that is declared as a common class ancestor, no, that is not possible. As a workaround you must determine the object class type and access it by typecasting to that class, or use RTTI which is more difficult.

Try something like this:

```
procedure TMyComp.Execute_FormShowModal;
var
  frm: TForm;
begin
  frm := TFormClass(FForm.ClassType).Create(FParentForm);

  { to acess the class specific members you will have to typecast to a
    specific class (or use RTTI, which is even more difficult) }
  if frm is TMyForm then
    TMyForm(frm).BtnOK.Enabled := False;

  frm.ShowModal;
  frm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I think OP has defined a form `FormUser: TFormUser` (class is just my guess, but not important). This form is not autocreated. Then he assigned the Form property of the component with FormUser (which of course is nil). Therefore the `FForm.ClassName` triggers the AV, as will also `FForm.ClassType`. Just a theory, he did not answer my last question.

Comment: @Tom, then the next comment by the question is not true. With the valid reference I meant a reference to a valid object (maybe I should have been more specific there). Still, you cannot typecast `ClassName` to the `TForm` class. Instead you need to work with metaclasses. Though I haven't tested the code from my answer (no Delphi by hand right now).

Comment: Well, he said he get an AV, also in another comment. I don't see how else his code would trigger an AV. You may want to consider this possibility as a possibility in your answer. Oh, and if he would have have assigned an existing form, he could use FormUser directly.

Comment: @Tom, if assigning a field value by not yet instantiated object declaration is not enough to determine the class type, you are right (as I said, I cannot verify this now). Feel free to use anything from this post to form your own (I can delete this one).